# Is it possible to debug exec() and system() calls with xdebug?

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm working on a legacy application which makes *very* heavy use of `system()` and `exec()` to run php scripts. The Xdebug session variables/headers don't seem to follow along once the `system()` call is executed.

Is it possible to somehow force PHP to *always* recognize downstream connections?

For example, `index.php` contains a line:

`exec('php some_script.php')`

Can I put a breakpoint in `some_script.php` and have the breakpoint registered with the debugger if I run index.php from the browser/cli?

Here's my xdebug.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.connect_back = 1
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_log = /var/log/xdebug.log
```

Comment: What do you mean by this? You certainly _can_ trace the `exec()` and `system()` calls themselves. You _can not_ somehow trace or debug the process that is forked by those calls. First because it is a separate process and second because it usually is not a php process, at least it is not executed in the same environment as your debugger. There simply is no connection between the two processes.

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. 

I think you answered, but allow me clarify:

Is it possible to somehow debug the script being executed by the `exec()` call? For example, `index.php` contains a line:

`exec('php some_script.php')`

Can I put a breakpoint in `some_script.php` and have the breakpoint registered with the debugger if I run index.php from the browser/cli?

Comment: In short: no, this is not possible.

Comment: Aw, fudge. It didn't seem likely, but I'm throwing a hail mary at this point.

Comment: Not sure if that Mary is interested in computer science or why one would want to hail her... but why can't you directly start the debugger with that script `some_script.php`?

Comment: That's one way of doing it, unfortunately sometimes these calls are executed with enormous variables/chained together... So `some_script.php` might itself actually have a `system()` call, and so on. Since I'm new to the project deciding which script to run is a pretty inefficient way to learn how the code works.

Comment: Hm, sounds like a very "exotic" architecture to me... But I don't know anything about that project. You will have your reasons for that strategy.

Comment: I definitely agree with that assessment! :) I suppose I am just paying for the sins of my forefathers. I appreciate your time & help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You just have to pass some xdebug options after `exec("php` .

In my case it is now:

```
if (extension_loaded('xdebug')) {
    $options = [
        '-d xdebug.mode=debug',
        '-d xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal'
    ];
}
$serializedOptions = implode(' ', $options);
exec("php $serializedOptions $cliPath $input", $output);
```

You may have to pass the xdebug zend_extension, I had to do it in another project, eg:

```
-d zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/xdebug.so
```